# WPF C# How to validate textbox input as Date format

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, entity-framework-6

I have some textboxes where the user enters a date or a time.
When I save on database I create

```
string input = txtdocumentiDate.Text +" "+ txtdocumentiTime.Text;
        ts.Documenti = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "dd/MM/yyyy HH.mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

(ts is my entity framework database table)

I would want to make a check to see if all the formats of my textboxes are valid before fire button save.

Comment: Is there a reason for not using the WPF [DatePicker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.aspx)? It is essentially a masked textbox that only allows a Date as input, thus would validate any of your data.

Comment: I tried use WPFToolKit DateTimePicker but i don t like how user interaction work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DateTime.TryParse`. It returns a bool value indicating whether the method was able to parse the string or not.

```
string input = txtdocumentiDate.Text +" "+ txtdocumentiTime.Text;
DateTime dummy;
if(DateTime.TryParse(input, dummy))
    ts.Documenti = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "dd/MM/yyyy HH.mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```